# PHP - Combining Multiple Items Into One

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am attempting to create an end-user page where I present different servers that are available to check-out.  A server at any given time can have either an "Available" status or a "Reserved" status.  I'm using a MySQL backend.  This is how I am doing my query:

```sql
SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'Available' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Amount
FROM products GROUP BY id
```

This is the result I get:

```
id,Server_Type,Status,Amount
1,BL460,Available,1
2,BL460,Available,1
3,BL460,Reserved,0
4,BL460,Reserved,0
5,BL460,Reserved,0
6,DL360,Available,1
7,DL360,Reserved,0
8,DL360,Reserved,0
```

Where `Reserved` is equal to 0, and `Available` is equal to 1.  I only want the end-user to be able to checkout a server in `Available` status.

To the question:  What I want to do in the page is present the list of servers on the page in this way, where `Available` is equal to the amount:

```
BL460 - Amount: 2
DL360 - Amount: 1
```

How can I achieve this format in PHP?

Comment: You should always mark your identifiers as such by using backticks. So surround `Status`, `Amount`, `products` and `id` with backticks. This will keep your queries valid even after a MySQL server update when [new reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html) are introduced which would elsewise collide with your identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that would probably be easier if you do it directly in your SQL query:

```
SELECT Server_Type, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM products WHERE Status = 'Available' GROUP BY Server_Type
```

This should give you exactly the table you want.

If you want to do it in PHP, the easiest solution would probably be to loop through your SQL result and count the number of available servers per `Server_Type` in an associative array where the `Server_Type` is your array key:

```
$amounts = array();

foreach($sql_result as $entry) {
    if($entry['Amount'] == 1) {
        if(isset($amounts[$entry['Server_Type']])) {
            $amounts[$entry['Server_Type']]++;
        } else {
            $amounts[$entry['Server_Type']] = 1;
        }
    }
}

echo $amounts;
```

**Edit:** in order to print the values as described in the question, you could use the following code snippet:

```
foreach($amounts as $name=>$amount) {
    echo $name + " - Amount: " + $amount + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I can't Group By Server_Type because then each unique item is not represented.  During the checkout phase, I need each "id" that the end-user selects to change from an "Available" status to a "Reserved" status.  I am not sure how else to accomplish this without an awareness of each unique id.

Comment: @Wes Well, you would have to do do separate `SELECT`s to achieve this then. As an alternative, have a look at the PHP based solution I just added; does that fulfil your requirements?

Comment: this is close.  The var_dump is giving me the result I would want, but still trying to figure out how to get it to present properly in an html format.

Comment: @Wes See my edit for a tip on how to print the values

Comment: Yes - you essentially answered what I asked.  But to further this, how can I represent Server_Type and the Amount as separate values that I can input into the page?  This route makes everything one result.  Is it even necessary to do what I am attempting to do?  Could I do a separate SELECT in my checkout process to achieve what I need?  EDIT:  Just saw your new post TimoSta, but it is not working.

Comment: Did you have a look at my edit? The solution actually gives you the Server_Type and the available amount for each Server_Type.

Comment: Well, I don't have enough infos to answer whether a separate SELECT during the checkout would be enough. On the current page, do you want the user to be able to select a certain entry with a specific id, or just any entry with a specific Server_Type?

Comment: The end-user doesn't need to be aware of the unique id.  They only need to be able to select from the available amount.  The checkout process can change each id by ASC order to Reserved if need be - doesn't matter as long as the Available items go to Reserved status.

Comment: Then you should be good loading the ids only during checkout. Note that the number of available Units can change between the point where the user selects his server type and the actual checkout if multiple users are active at the same time -- you would need to somehow handle this during the checkout.

Comment: Ok - Let me try that route then.  Thanks a bunch for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a crosstab query -

```
SELECT `Status`,
SUM(IF(`Server_Type` = 'BL460' AND `Status` = 'Available', `Amount`, 0)) AS `BL460`,
SUM(IF(`Server_Type` = 'DL360' AND `Status` = 'Available', `Amount`, 0)) AS `DL360`
FROM `products`
GROUP BY `Status`
```

Your table would look like this -

```
Status    |    BL460    |    DL360    |
Available |        2    |        1    |
Reserved  |        0    |        0    |
```

Here is an [EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7b47/3)

Even better would be to flip things around -

```
SELECT `server_type`,
SUM(IF(`status` = 'Available', 1, 0)) AS `Available`,
SUM(IF(`status` = 'Reserved', 1, 0)) AS `Reserved`
FROM `servers`
GROUP BY `server_type`;
```

Which would result in a table that looks like this (based on data in the fiddle) -

```
server_type    |    Available    |    Reserved
BL460          |            3    |           1
DL360          |            1    |           2
```

Here is that [EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7b47/5)

Here I could continue to add servers to the table without having to worry about adding them to the query as you would have to do in the first query. If you add an additional status you would have to change the query.

Note in both cases there is *no need for an `Amount` column* as the status is the item counted. By placing the load on the database server it makes it much easier to output the HTML as you are just going row bu row as you normally would.

Comment: Thanks!  Let me look at this method as well.  I will report back shortly.

Comment: Hey Jay - the issue with this is that I lose the "id" column, and I need to keep that so that each item remains unique.

Comment: If you look at the example there is still an id column, so none of the uniqueness is lost @Wes